# Encrypting large files (2GB) using AES/CBC/PKCS5padding

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have very large file about 2GB and i want to encrypt it by cutting it on chunks, if I read it at once its too big and my JVM throws OutOfMemory Error. I am using **AES**/CBC/PKCS5padding. Can you recommend me a way to do it? I read about CipherStreams but I am not sure if they would work. Thanks in advance!
I am using this strategy right now, but its not working for bigger files.

```
  try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(in);
                 FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(out)) {
                byte[] encoded = cipher.doFinal(ByteStreams.toByteArray(input));
                output.write(encoded);
            }
```

Comment: The problem is in Java. Java stores all then encrypt. Why don't you use authenticated encryption like AES-GCM?

Comment: @kelalaka Java doesn't store all then encrypt if you use `Cipher*Stream` correctly.  AES-GCM, however, is not a good fit for large files like this.  It is the one instance where I would recommend CBC + HMAC over GCM.

Comment: Have a look at `cipher. update(..)` method, it helps you to decrypt the stream in chunks (just do not read the whole file into memory)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `CipherOutputStream` wrapping your `FileOuputStream`.

Use `Files.copy()` to copy your file to this `CipherOutputStream`.

Done.
Read the javadoc for details.